# jquerymobile pageShow , PrevPage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 3 JqueryMobile pages:

Page1,Page2 and Page3

every one can navigate to Page3, I'm using this code:

```
        $('#Page3').on('pageshow', function (object) {
            //  Change enabled status 
            $('#MenuItemEnPedido').find('a').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass('ui-disabled');
            });
            $('#PagDocumentoOpcionDetalle').removeClass('ui-disabled');
        });
```

To change some options, but i need to know the id of **object** page returned by pageshow event.
Not target id, just prevPage Id.

Comment: You need to know the ID of the previous page? Why not just save it in the closure (ie: in `$('#Page3'.on('pageshow'` set `currpage = '#Page3';`)

Comment: I need to know the previous page because depending on source page, some options could change, actually i know the target page **Page3** but i need to know if source page was **Page1** or **Page2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example how to retrieve last page data from jQM: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/mfC8j/

During pagebeforeshow event you can access last page data and use it for next one:

```
$('#page2').on('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
    alert(data.prevPage.attr('id'));
});
```

prevPage is an object that contains whole last page.

Comment: Yes it works fine. But is most recomended use **on** instead **live** `('#page2').on('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
    alert(data.prevPage.attr('id'));
});`

Comment: Yes, use .on( if you have a new version of jQuery.