# Jquery Mobile - Getting Element Value in Previous Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have page1:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home-page" >
    <div data-role="content">
            ...
        <input id="el1" type="text" />
            ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Page1 contains link which will load page2 (via ajax):

If page2 was loaded, how to access an element in page1? Is it possible?

```
$('#page2').die('pageinit');
$('#page2').live('pageinit', function(event, data){
    //?
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13797984/1848600. It will show you how to access previous page Data.

You can use this code to access it:

```
$('#second').on('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
    alert(data.prevPage.find('div[data-role="content"]').attr('id'));
});
```

I have also created a new example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Y5DuV/. If you have more questions give me a comment.